# Rails 3 vs. Rails 2 Routing Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing

I have been following a tutorial @ [Noupe](http://www.noupe.com/ajax/create-a-simple-twitter-app.html) with the intention of learning Rails. It's going well and the app works, but I gather it was written for Rails 2, so there are some deprecated pieces of code used.

While I have resolved most of these, I have one remaining problem with the routing. The Rails 2 code in the tutorial is:

`ActionController::Routing::Routes.draw do |map|

  map.resources :posts

  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'

  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'

end`

This works fine, but it is the old code. I have attempted to rewrite the code as follows:

`Twitter::Application.routes do

  resources :posts

  match ':controller/:action/:id'

  match ':controller/:action/:id.:format'

end`

This results in an error when I attempt to visit http://localhost:3000/posts -

Routing Error
No route matches "/posts"

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong? I did notice that I get a compiler error if I write twitter in the first line (instead of Twitter) - since my app is named twitter, I thought this might be the issue, but it does not seem to be.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are missing the call to the method draw. Try to change the first line to the following:

```
Twitter::Application.routes.draw do
```

Comment: For reference, the reason I hadn't done that already was section 7.3 of the Rails3 release notes - they indicate an example that does not include the draw method.